# Mixed effect model with one vs two random slopes

Tags: r, mixed-model

I am running a multilevel model in R looking at the responses of 5 different groups of participants across 4 conditions. I am adding individual random effects to account for the variability among participant. I am however unsure if this would be better by just using a random intercept and slope for the condition variable such as:

```
response ~ 1 + group * condition + (1 + condition | participant)
```

Or if it would be better to use:

```
response ~ 1 + group * condition + 
           (1 + group * condition | participant)
```

I am not quite sure if the second one would be necessary at all for the purpose I described before, and I am new to hierarchical models, so I was wondering what additional information is the second model giving to me compared to the first one?

Comment: Is the variable "participant" nested in the variable "group"? If it is so, you need a nested model. In other words: "' response ~ 1 + condition + ( 1 + condition | Group ) + ( 1 + condition | Group:Participants ) '"

Comment: That is what I am wondering, all groups have the unique set of participants, but I don't want to generalize among groups, I want to know the estimates from each of them. I am unsure if I should run the analysis with nested random effects in that case.